# rails fields validate if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation

I have a Model `Product` with fields:

```
name price product_type_id:integer size:string page_quantity:integer.
```

How can make this validation work for `Product` model `create` action?

```
- if product_type.id == "1"
   validates :size, presence: true
   validates :page_quantity, presence:false
- else
   validates :size, presence: false
   validates :page_quantity, presence:true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   validates :size, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |p| p.product_type_id == "1" } 
   validates :page_quantity, presence:false, if: Proc.new { |p| p.product_type_id == "1" }
   validates :size, presence: false, unless: Proc.new { |p| p.product_type_id == "1" }
   validates :page_quantity, presence:true, unless: Proc.new { |p| p.product_type_id == "1" }
end
```

Comment: I want the validation to be not to `Product.id` but `if product_type_id == 1` in Product.create action

Comment: @makerbreaker adjusted, but I think that the main idea should be pretty clear.